# voting/reputation questions

Tags: support, voting

Ive been getting into stackoverflow.  Its addictive.

1. Sometimes I answer a question, and I was wondering if someone has to vote it up, or if it gets a default 1 vote if there are no other answers.  In others words, if an answer has a vote, did someone vote for my response?  I just ask because it seems like after every answer i post, i go back 10 minutes later and there is a vote.
2. it would be really nice if we could get emails whenever there is an update to a comment on a question the user has answered.  I find checking the 'email me every day' functionality doesn't work so good.
3. Is there a way to see who is voting for your responses?

thanx

Comment: I use one of the Firefox plugins that goes "ding!" whenever I get upvoted, because I love to hear dinging during my workday :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. there is no automated voting; someone voted for you; there is lots of traffic
2. no, there isn't any vote e-mailing (although you can get e-mails to indicate new answers to a question you asked). You could use something like [Jon's tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=305644&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showzero=true&showflair=true) though (which is what I use)
3. no, by design - unless you suspect something nefarious; in which case just flag something for moderator attention (explaining why) and we'll take a look (and we still won't tell you who ;p)

Comment: thanx thats what i suspected.

Comment: Just curious, how exactly is Jon's tracker gathering the vote score information about any user? I didn't expect it to be public accessible.

Comment: @BalusC - there is a whole API around this data (see http://stackapps.com/); however, Jon's page pre-dates this - I *believe* it still uses the less official (but still sanctioned) JSON API that the site itself uses for the user/rep page.